# Boost bimap find with multiset_of

Tags: c++, boost, bimap, boost-bimap

I have question with Boost::bimap and could not find answer from boost document.

```
using AToBBimap = boost::bimap< boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of<CString>, boost::bimaps::multiset_of<CString> >; //hashed bimap
using AToBBimapValueT = AToBBimap ::value_type;

AToBBimap bi_map;
bi_map.insert(AToBBimapValueT{"message1", "value"});
bi_map.insert(AToBBimapValueT{"message2", "value"});

bi_map.right.find("value");
```

QUESTION: with `bi_map.right.find("value")` looks like can only get iterator to `{"message1", "value"}`, is there possible to get a list of both matching like `[{"message1", "value"}, {"message2", "value"}]`?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is `equal_range("value")`, like  with `std::multiset` and `std::multimap`.

That member returns a pair of iterators, which is conveniently compatible with Boost's iterator-range factory, so you can use it:

```
for (auto p : boost::make_iterator_range(bi_map.right.equal_range("value")))
        do something with p.second;
```